# qgis legend with calculated field symbol

Tags: qgis, legend

I am making a map with a bunch of features plotted on it, each with a two-letter combination used as the symbol and a color. The letters are unique for each feature, drawn from a column containing the letter combination for each feature.
(That is, this is not a "label" per se, but a font symbol with a field being used as the input).

It works fine on the map itself, but when I want to output the legend, the symbols aren't being shown correctly, in stead qgis just shows a placeholder A on every single line in the legend.

Is there anything I can do to make this work?
I don't want to have to print the letters manually, because I have more than 2000 unique features (letter combination + color).